# Why is there a "pouvoir" in the sentence "Où mon chien a-t-il bien pu partir?"

Tags: grammaire

Why is there a "pouvoir" and a "bien" in the sentence

> Où mon chien a-t-il bien pu partir ?

(Where did my dog go?)

It literally translates to

> Where could my dog go?

So I don't understand how that translates to

> Where did my dog go?

Comment: A way that helps me (an anglophone) **a little** to understand the purpose of “pouvoir” in your sentence … one that doesn’t require going from an infinitive (partir) in French to a present perfect form (have gone) in English … is by interpreting “partir” to mean “be” (or to keep it closer to its true meaning, to mean “be off to”): … “Where could my dog [possibly] **be**?” …  “Where could he [possibly] **be off to**?”  (Also, the “[possibly]” might **possibly** correspond with the “bien”) +1

Comment: In that strange language, English: *Where could my dog have gone?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal translation of auxiliaries does not really make sense. "Pouvoir", here, have the meaning of "may" or "could" so it should be translated as:

> Where could my dog have gone

With this sentence, you are not asking about where the dog actually went, but about where the dog could have possibly gone.
"bien" is here to mark the rhetorical nature of the question. Usually you ask this question to yourself as it seems you looked for every place where the dog may have been. You don't expect anybody to suddenly show up with the answer, even if that would be great.

Comment: Ah merci beaucoup! La phrase est censé être "Where could my dog have gone"

Comment: @MorganFR: "May" carries the ambiguity between the capacity and the hypothesis that "pouvoir" contains. I don't feel like "might" or "could" do that as well.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm no english scholar but I rarely hear "may" used in such a place. I'd much rather use "could" "Where could my dog have gone" rather than "Where may my dog have gone". I mostly here it only with the first person

Comment: Like with the word shall,

Comment: I don't care about making my answer idiomatic, this is about explaining how the French sentence works, not about finding the perfect translation in English.

Answer (score 1):

*Où mon chien est-il parti ?* : question simple - on se demande où le chien est parti.

*Où mon chien a-t-il pu partir ?* : interrogation plus forte: sous-entendu: on ne sait plus où il est, et on se demande où .

*Où mon chien a-t-il bien pu partir ?* : interrogation encore plus forte: sous-entendu: on ne sait pas du tout où il est parti, et on n'imagine pas d'endroit.